# How to list the kubernetes pods based on any particular exit code, for example i need to list all the pods which has exitCode value 255

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates

How to list the kubenetes pods based on any particular exitCode value. For example i need to list all the pods which has exitCode value = 255.

I have tried below command and it will give all pods along with all exitcodes.

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{..exitCode}{'\n'}{end}"

kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{..exitCode}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly you may want to check out the [Field Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/).

> Field selectors let you select Kubernetes resources based on the value
>   of one or more resource fields. Here are some example field selector
>   queries:
>
> - metadata.name=my-service
> - metadata.namespace!=default
> - status.phase=Pending
>
> This kubectl command selects all Pods for which
>   the value of the status.phase field is Running:
>
> `kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running`

Here is some more [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) regarding this.

> Selector (field query) to filter on, supports '=',
>   '==', and '!='.(e.g. --field-selector key1=value1,key2=value2). The
>   server only supports a limited number of field queries per type.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command to get the list of pod based on particular error code:

kubectl get pods  $(for i in  0 255; do kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath={.items[?(@..exitCode==$i)].metadata.name} ; echo ;done)

And we can use below command to delete pods based on particular error codes:

kubectl delete pods $(for i in  0 255; do kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath={.items[?(@..exitCode==$i)].metadata.name} ; echo ;done)

where value in for loop i.e 0 255 etc is the error code, you can give any error code here and then run this command.

Answer (score 0):

To list the pods based on exit code use the below command :

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{..exitCode}{'\n'}{end}" | grep 255`